How to Plot a Sigmoidal Curve to a Dose-Response to Find the Saturation Point and EC50

Hi there, I have injected voltage (mV) on the x-axis (not a log scale) and the neural response of the network (as area under the curve (AUC))) on the y. The data also includes a sample size of n = 8 wells for each voltage and a SE of the area for each data point. While I can visualise approximately where the saturation point is, I would like something more mathematically/statistically rigorous.
Cheers!

Please tell us specifically what you mean by a "sigmoid."  This means different things in different contexts and the title of your graphic references two mathematically different forms of it!

Welcome to Cross Validated! A heading at the top of the image says: "Fit a dose-response model (e.g., Hill equation or Michaelis-Menten kinetics) Estimate EC50." That sounds like this might be a homework or self-study problem. That's OK on this site, but then please add the self-study tag, explain the work you've done so far, and where you are stuck. For example, have you learned what the Hill equation or Michaelis-Menten kinetics? Also, more information on the source of the underlying data (spike counts) would help; sometimes counts need to be modeled differently from continuous outcomes.

Hi @whuber, I have injected selected voltages (not on a log scale) from 100-2000mV, increasing by 100mV steps. I then looked at the neural network response (bursts), and counted the spike events within network bursts. The level seems to be saturating at about 1200mV. I do not believe a regular Hill equation is appropriate, as the x-axis is not a log scale.
I am using GraphPad Prism, and need something like this: https://www.graphpad.com/support/faq/fitting-dose-response-data-that-are-sigmoidal-when-x-is-concentration-rather-than-logconcentration/

Y=Bottom+(Top-Bottom)*x^n/(Ka^n+x^n)

What you have written and linked to in your comments is one form of the Hill equation, generalized to allow for a non-zero Bottom and an unscaled Top value on the vertical axis (instead of the frequent pre-scaling of the vertical axis to a range of 0 to 100). Although plots are often done with a log-scaled x axis, the choice of x axis scaling for display doesn't affect the underlying mathematical relationship for estimation. Try fitting the equation that you provided. In that form Ka is the x-axis value at half saturation (called EC50 in the annotation of your plot).

Hi @EdM and @whuber I actually got ChatGPT to help me write a Python code using that formula, and I got this: (!)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

That's an excellent start.  But don't omit the next step, which is assessing the lack of fit: there are clear departures from the fit at both ends of the curve and you ought to be interested in whether there is strong evidence for that and what it might mean for understanding and interpreting the fit.

Sure, ChatGPT gives a quick result (which I find amazing) but then we should carefully quality control that result as @whuber commented.
